# Role of comma when adding a dictionary entry in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple question.

I have a dictionary: `table = collections.defaultdict(set)`, and a previously defined grammar consisting of rules like the following:

```
Rule(('Noun', ('money',)))
Rule(('Noun', ('book',)))
Rule(('S', ('book',)))
```

Now, when I type this, nothing happens.

```
for rule in grammar:
    if rule.symbols == ("book"):
        table[col - 1, col].add(rule.head)
```

When I type this, the entry is added.

```
for rule in grammar:
    if rule.symbols == ("book",):
        table[col - 1, col].add(rule.head)
```

The only difference between the two is the comma behind "book". What does this comma do and why is it necessary?

Comment: Well, what's `rule`, specifically `rule.symbols`?

Comment: For example, with `Rule(('Noun', ('money',)))`, rule.symbols would be `('money')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `("book")` the parens are just a way of grouping the expression.  The value of that expression is just the string `"book"`.

In the second case, it's creating a tuple, with one element in it.

Answer (score 4):

You need add comma to make it a tuple, otherwise it's just a string.

Comment: So adding a comma behind a string makes the computer reads it as a tuple?

Comment: Adding a comma behind any *expression* creates a 1-element tuple containing that expression's value. ;-)

Comment: @delnan yes, in this case the input is string.

Comment: It's worth highlighting that parentheses are not required to make a tuple, just the comma: `a = 1,2,3` is perfectly valid, as is `b = 1,`. In ambiguous cases, of course (like passing arguments to a function) the parentheses can be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

One is string, second is tuple (,):

```
>>> ("book")
'book'
>>> ("book",)
('book',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma transform the expression type from `str` (with useless parenthesis around) to `tuple` with single element.

Use `type()` to see this in action:

```
>>> type(("book"))
<class 'str'>
>>> type(("book",))
<class 'tuple'>
```